# UIWebView - What load times should I expect?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I have had a look through lots of posts but can't seem to find anything on UIWebView load times and the kind of performance to expect.

I have an app that calls in a cached html page which is about 4.2KB in size. The view takes around 3.5 seconds to render through a wi-fi connection. How good or bad is this?

I'm trying to get the page as quick as possible but I can't really find anything more I can do. So I guess the question is, should I be getting better performance than this?

Any useful links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't have much to do with the size of the HTML. Although 4.2Kb is rather big. Rendering performance is mostly related to "what" it renders. For example, if you have lots of tables, or even worse -- nested tables --, then the rendering will be really slow. If you're HTML uses bad recursive entity definitions, it'll be horribly slow too. I would recommend taking full advantage of HTML5 for complex rendering.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've spent so much time looking at the app side of things I neglected looking at it from the html side. I'll see if I can gain any improvements there.